# User behavior tracking system for QT desktop application like Hotjar

Tags: qt

Is there any good "out of the box" tracking system that looks like Hotjar (funnels, mouse movement tracking, time spend on widgets) that can be used in a QT dock-able widget application? We would like to see user behavior so we can improve the interface. Our application is a little tricky because it's an offline system, so we also need to store in the user machine and submit the data for us for when the user checks for updates, but most of the time this system will be off the internet when it's being used.

Comment: Daniel, I don't know of an out of the box solution, though it would be nice to know of one, but you maybe able to roll your own rudimentary tracking system by intercepting events in your main window.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HotJar seems pretty good from a functional standpoint, but it is collecting everything users type into the site is a bad idea from a security standpoint. I would only use it for test sessions or sites that do use POI. Your putting all your users information and data at risk.